# How to start a program with Python?

Tags: python, load

How to start a program with Python?

I thougt this would be very easy like:

```
open(r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe")
```

But nothing happens.
How to do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should accept the answer that seems best.  If more than one answer is good and right, you can still up-vote both of them.

Comment: WHichever one works better for you.  If you just need to execute a command and wait until it's done, use `call`.  If you need to get output from the command, feed it input, or have it run while your program continues (i.e. in parallel), use `Popen`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general you can do that using `subprocess.call`

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe")
```

But if all you want to do is open a page in a browser you can do:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.open('http://stackoverflow.com/')
True
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html and http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html .

Answer (score 7):

You are opening the file to read its content, instead try subprocess module

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe"])
```

Answer (score 2):

try `os.system()` and read up on alternatives in the `subprocess` module.